# How do you properly handle device orientation from an android native only application?

Tags: android, opengl-es

The objective is to make a simple 2d arrow compass application like the one from the book [iPhone 3D Programming](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596804822) [here](http://examples.oreilly.com/9780596804831/readme.html#HelloArrow) that rotates smoothly in response to orientation changes.

AndroidManifest.xml (Subscribe to orientation changes)

```
<activity android:name="android.app.NativeActivity"
 android:label="@string/app_name"
 android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden">
```

AndroidApp.cpp (Get angle of rotation)

```
void AndroidApp::handleCmd (int32_t cmd) {
switch (cmd) {
    case APP_CMD_CONFIG_CHANGED:
       // Your code here
    break;
  }
}
```

RenderingEngine.cpp (Store angle to rotate the arrow when rendering the scene)

```
    void RenderingEngine::OnRotate(DeviceOrientation orientation)
    {
       float angle = 0;

       switch (orientation) {
          case DeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft:
             angle = 270;
             break;

          case DeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown:
             angle = 180;
             break;

          case DeviceOrientationLandscapeRight:
             angle = 90;
             break;
       }

       m_desiredAngle = angle;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make the rotation smooth you should use compass instead of orientation change event.

I suggest checking out the documentation for [NativeActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NativeActivity.html). There is an example with accelerometer:

```
// Prepare to monitor accelerometer
engine.sensorManager = ASensorManager_getInstance();
engine.accelerometerSensor = ASensorManager_getDefaultSensor(engine.sensorManager,
        ASENSOR_TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
engine.sensorEventQueue = ASensorManager_createEventQueue(engine.sensorManager,
        state->looper, LOOPER_ID_USER, NULL, NULL);
```

Probably there is more info in Android NDK documentation which you can find in `<ndk>/docs` directory ([source](http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/overview.html#docs)).